# Why won't CSS transformations render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I have made a box that rotates on the X axis as you scroll up and down the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(finish_rotation, delay);
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop() * 2;
    animate_rotation();
});
function animate_rotation(){    
    var translate = 'rotateX(' + scroll + 'deg)';
    $('.flipper').css('transform', translate);
}
```

When you stop scrolling I have it complete its rotation to the nearest multiple of 180, so that it completes its rotation. This is being done in finish_scroll.

```
function finish_rotation (){
    var goal_rotation = 180*Math.ceil(scroll/180);
    while(scroll < goal_rotation){
        scroll++;
        animate_rotation();
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesn't actually animate the rest of the rotation, it goes right to the finished position. I can confirm that animate_rotation is being called for each iteration in finish_rotation's while loop, but I can't figure out why the animation doesn't seem to be happening. I thought that maybe the animations were happening too fast or too close together so I tried changing the amount I increment scroll, and adding a setTimeout on each animate_rotation call, but it still won't animate all of the steps. Why won't all of the animations play out?

For a working example check here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/bc0rne5t/5/)

**EDIT:** I have updated the fiddle so that the flipping accommodates scrolling up and down. This change hasn't change the transformation problem, so for readability I am going to leave the code in the question as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finish_rotation()` function seem to go right to the finish position because it's going too fast. To see an animation, you need to set a timeout in the loop.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
function finish_rotation (){
    var goal_rotation = 180*Math.ceil(scroll/180);

    setTimeout(function(){
        scroll++;
        animate_rotation();
        if (scroll < goal_rotation)
            finish_rotation();
    }, 10);
}
```

[Updated JsFilled here](http://jsfiddle.net/bc0rne5t/6/)

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop is synchronous, so it will finish processing before anything is rendered to the page.

Consider using this `finish_rotation` function:

```
function finish_rotation() {
    var goal_rotation = 180*Math.ceil(scroll/180);
    $('.flipper').css({
        "transition" : "transform "+((goal_rotation-scroll)*10)+"ms linear",
        // Adjust that *10 as needed for your desired speed
        "transform" : "rotate("+goal_rotation+"deg)"
    }).one("transitionend",function() {
        $(this).css({"transition":""});
    });
}
```

You may need to add further code in your `window.scroll` block, to unbind the `transitionend` event and remove the `transition` property as well, otherwise scrolling while the transition is still in progress may cause issues.